# Android Google Maps: Add marker in the middle of country

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am working on an android application where I have integrated google map and added marker on it at user's current location. I have used location API for tracking users location. Now client wants me to show this marker in the middle of the country where user resides instead of his location.

I haven't found any way of doing that yet. Is it possible to achieve that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not official way found. I thought. You can do it manually as per @CommonsWare answer

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Create yourself a database of the locations of middles of countries, for whatever your definition is of "middle".

Step #2: Ask the user in which country she resides.

Step #3: Look up the location of the middle of that country in the database from Step #1.

Step #4: Put a marker at that location.

Comment: @CommansWare: Thank you for the answer. I can use geocoding to get user's address(country) from his tracked location. But is maintaining database the only way to achieve this?

Comment: @user2235057: I do not know how else you plan on getting the "middle" of a country.